# i am having a problem deploying my app on heroku (node.js)

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

hi i am getting a problem while trying to deploy my app on heruko
the following error

and my Procfile looks like 
web: npm start

````
2019-10-25T03:31:44.445209+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=andela-api.herokuapp.com request_id=ee3f68c6-e7a5-4212-8277-bddd8a33027c fwd="41.186.25.0" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https```
````

Comment: In which folder is your 'favicon.ico' present?

Comment: i don't have such a file

Comment: how do I create it?

Comment: If you don't have "favicon.ico" or don't want to use one, simply delete the line which refers to the icon path, in your app index file.

Answer (score 0):

Favicon file is an image file(usually website logo) that you see on the browser tab. It has extension `.ico`. Your project cannot find that file.

1. If you do not have `favicon.ico` file in your project, then create one and upload it at suitable location(make sure it's accessible via url `/favicon.ico`).
2. If you have favicon file in your project, the problem is related to permission to access the file via `/favicon.ico` (make sure the folder where you have the file stored is public so that it can be access via url `/favicon.ico`)

**How to create favicon file?**
Use favicon generator site such [this one](https://www.favicon-generator.org/). Upload your logo file and download the favicon generated by the site.

Answer (score 0):

I had react app and after deploying to heroku I got the same error. The reason of this, I deleted favicon.ico and manifest.json files in public folder. After adding favicon.ico and manifest.json files in public folder, the error solved.